react-native-slider not sliding smoothly
I'm having an issue with onValueChange when the Slider is in TabButton... it looks like it's glitching but because of the constant callbacks it's not sliding smoothly and stops on every change.
I Used the Slider outside of the TabButton and it works smoothly and fine.
Is there a way to have the same effect inside the TabButton?
const handleValueChange = debounce((value) => {
    setSliderValue(value);
  }, 100);

  const TabButton = ({ tabName, label }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            styles.tabBarItem,
            {
              borderColor: selectedTab === tabName ? COLORS.info_700 : COLORS.gray,
              borderRadius: 50,
            },
          ]}
          onPress={() => {
            handleTabPress(tabName);
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: selectedTab === tabName ? COLORS.white : COLORS.gray,
              ...FONTS.h4_reg,
            }}
          >
            {label}
          </Text>


        </TouchableOpacity>
        {isDropdownVisible && selectedTab === tabName && (
          <View style={styles.dropdown}>
            ...
            {selectedTab === 'Distance' && (
              <View >
                <Slider
                  style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
                  step={1}
                  minimumValue={0}
                  maximumValue={100}
                  minimumTrackTintColor={COLORS.info_700}
                  maximumTrackTintColor={COLORS.black}

                  value={sliderValue}
                  onValueChange={handleValueChange}

                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>{sliderValue} KM</Text> 
                
              </View>
            )}

          </View>
        )}
        
      </View>
    );
  };

<View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
            <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <View style={styles.tabBar}>
                <TabButton tabName="Age" label="Age" />
                <TabButton tabName="Gender" label="Gender" />
                <TabButton tabName="Goal" label="Goal" />
                <TabButton tabName="Distance" label="Distance" />
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>


